# Zend Framework Doctrine create entity with ManyToMany

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, jquery-select2

I'm using `Zend Framework 2 with Doctrine`.

I have two entities with ManyToMany relations, Portfolio and Tag.

When I'm editing Portfolio, I use `select2` and I have possibility to not only select existing Tags, but also create new Tag from text input.

Can someone give me advice how to implement creation of new Tag? Seems like this case (zf2, doctrine, select2) is typical. Is there built-in methods to create new entities?

Answer (score 0):

Logically **Many to Many** relationships should be resolved into **One to Many** with a new table.

if you can post your table schema I will create you the complete model/entity.